# mvn --version is showing java usage options

Tags: maven

I am trying to run maven on my machine, I am facing the below error. All the paths are correct, but not sure why this is showing up. 
[image]

Comment: Try opening `{maven_install_dir}/bin/mvn.bat`, find line starting with `%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% %MAVEN_OPTS%`, and add `echo ` before it. So that it will become `echo %MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% .....`. Then rerun `mvn --version` and tell us what it prints.

Comment: Where can I find %MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% %MAVEN_OPTS%. I had executed mvn.bat. It is showing build failure.

Comment: Edit the bat file with notepad or something.

Comment: what are the paths? JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME etc? It seems you pointed one of the paths to a binary instead of the path.